# How can electrons flow through superconductive material

Tags: superconductors

I am a little confused. Metals has enormous number of free electrons but low carrier mobility. It means that electrons are moving slowly but large amount simultaneously. Lets say you pass current through wire and measure voltage diference on it. Then if you divide this voltage by wire length you get electric field. It will be small because voltage drop is small but it will be right amount for moving your current. And now lets cool down a wire for temperature near 0K. The metal will become superconductive. So you can't measure voltage difference because the resistance is 0 ohm, hence you have zero electric field so how can electrons flow through?

Comment: Try Physics SE. Also, don't mistake for the inability to measure a voltage as lack of an electric field. Where there is smoke, there is fire, but that doesn't mean that if there is no smoke then there is no fire.

Comment: Start with the wikipedia article on superconductivity.  It's not entirely clear that the physics are fully understood by anyone, though there are theories proposed.

Comment: Ohm's law does not work well for ideal conductors (zero resistance).

Comment: @EugeneSh. division by zero is... discouraged

Comment: @ChrisStratton I imagined the knight templar in Indiana Jones Last Crusade saying this when he is talking about the grail selection results.

Comment: In fact, even if the physics is not understood intuitively, the math describing what is going on is fully developed.

Comment: @DKNguyen a chalice made of room temperature superconductor would be interesting indeed  (apparently it's possible, you just need... a really big rock to compress it)

Comment: The multiplicative form of Ohm's law works fine with super-conductors. E = IR (or V=IR). If R is 0, so is E, regardless of the value of I.

Comment: nobody is dividing by zero that's why you use current source

Comment: OK, googled it for you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62664/how-can-ohms-law-be-correct-if-superconductors-have-0-resistivity

Comment: This is why my physics professors called it Ohm's *Rule*.

Comment: @Aaron but Siemens win.  Resistance is futile!

Comment: @andz Superconduction is due to the formation of Cooper pairs -- a bosonic (integer spin) composite. They no longer act like fermions. Start with Bardeen, Schrieffer, and of course Cooper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should keep the following distinction in mind:

**Ideal Conductors (temperature doesn't matter)**
Ideal conductors have zero resistivity and hence infinite conductivity. But they are just idealized connection used in lumped models circuits. You can still treat the indeterminacy of the ratio j = E / sigma (the local form of Ohm's law) as a 0/0 kind of limit that gives a finite value for j.
Try to see this in this way, the resistivity of the 'ideal conductor' connection is so low, that you only need and infinitesimally small electric field in order to sustain the finite current through it.

So, you can still think of Ohm's law (as defined in lumped circuit theory) to hold, albeit in the limit.

**Real Conductors (at low temperatures)**
To successfully quantitatively explain conductivity in the real world you need quantum mechanics. The classical model of Drude (and even the semiclassical model of Sommerfeld) are not able to explain experimental data, especially at low temperatures (where low means in the single digit kelvins).

In the quantum theory of conductivity, the electron is seen as a wave (packet) interacting with the periodic potential of the atomic lattice of the material. It might surprise you, but if the lattice is perfectly periodic - that is it has no defects, impurities and it does not change its structure - this theory does not predict any resistivity for a real conductor. The electron will travel unimpeded in the material just like light would propagate unattenuated in a perfectly transparent crystal (the transparency is a consequence of the absence of impurities, defects or deformations).
What explains resistivity (and the exchange of energy between electron and the lattice) are imperfections in the lattice. They can be of two kinds: impurities and defects, and vibrations (that, in the quantum realm, are quantized in the form of phonons).

Now, by reducing T near zero kelvins, you can eliminate the vibrations and the associated electron-phonon interactions that lead to the resistivity you can experience at 'human' temperatures, but you cannot get rid of the impurities and defects in the materials. The result is that real conductors at very low temperatures will exhibit a residual resistivity rho_zero and you will not see superconducting behavior.

[image: fig residual resistivity]
source: http://what-when-how.com/electronic-properties-of-materials/electrical-conduction-in-metals-and-alloys-electrical-properties-of-materials-part-2/

Copper is a metal that behaves this way.
As you can see, you will not see R->0 as T->0, so there is no paradox. You do not even need the passage to the limit adopted to explain ideal conductors.

**Superconductors (below critical temperature)**
Superconductors are a different story, and here the effect is doubly weird. Due to an exclusively quantum interaction between electrons, the resistivity of these materials actually drops to zero under a certain temperature. The way resistivity change with temperature is like this

[image: fig superconductivity]
source: https://www.ques10.com/p/31326/define-super-conductivity-and-critical-temperature/

but when you are in the 'superconducting state' you have already kissed goodbye to Ohm's law, so there is no point in my opinion to treat this case as if Ohm's law was still applicable.

Comment: Superconductors can't carry an infinite amount of current either. It breaksdown when the current density gets too high. And they still have inductance!

Comment: @DKNguyen sure, resistance goes to zero, but if you have current circulating (in a... circle or sort of) you will also have self-inductance that will limit the current to a finite value. But I believe the OP was confused by the use of the term 'superconductor' in lieu of ideal or perfect conductor (in the sense used in circuit theory).